# Force Chrome Extension Shortcut at Install

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, copy-paste

OI am trying to create a chrome extension that does not allow CTRL+C or V so that users cannot use the copy and paste function at a facility using a locked down laptop.

My manifest looks like this

```
"commands": {
  "do-nothing0": {
     "Suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+C"
     },
     "description": "Do nothing"
  },
```

However, I cannot get CTRL+C to be forced in the Extensions Shortcut page.
[Picture Of Extension Shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6HYU.png)

In the js file I only have this.

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(a){});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Tangential to the question at hand, but are you aware that `CTRL+C` and `CTRL+V` are not the only ways to perform copy and paste (respectively)? To truly prevent anything from being copy/pasted, you'll need to get *way* deeper (at an operating system level) to truly disable such functionality. If data exfiltration via the keyboard is truly a concern, have you also blocked off the ability to take screenshots, send/receive files, etc.?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. These are nurses and they are "lazy" copying yesterdays notes into todays note. We have blocked context menu also with a plugin from chrome. We are not concerned with any other form of copying. The devices them selves are fully locked down to chrome anyway.